# join file binary with text to create POST request body - python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, python-requests

I'm trying to upload file to Google Drive using their API.

According to their specification, the body of the POST request should look like this:

```
--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "My File"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

JPEG data
--foo_bar_baz--
```

Assuming I have a path to the *JPEG file*, how to construct the request's body (*"load the file plus prepend and append the text to it"*)?

Thank you.

PS: Please don't suggest Google Client Library. It's about creating the request's body:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you don't want to use the actual client library.

Comment: @DanielRoseman different story:) Maybe because it should work anywhere else. The question is how to construct the request. That should be worth to know:) GDrive is there just for the context.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Advanced Usage](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/),

> Requests supports streaming uploads, which allow you to send large streams or files without reading them into memory. To stream and upload, simply provide a file-like object for your body:

```
with open('massive-body', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f)
```

However, please note that it is strongly recommended that you open files in binary mode. This is because Requests may attempt to provide the Content-Length header for you, and if it does this value will be set to the number of bytes in the file. **Errors may occur if you open the file in text mode.**

This [Quickstart](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) will be helpful too.